# Instances of IHandleMessages created by call/request

Tags: nservicebus

I have some doubs about the mechanism that NServiceBus follow to create instances of IHandleMessages:

1. Does it create one instance per call or could it be reuse?
2. Is it safe to have private state on handlers? (for clean code purpose)

Answer (score 3):

Message handlers are not designed to maintain state between invocations. A new instance is created for each handling of a message and while you *could* have private static state on the handler, it's strongly discouraged. One reason for this is if the handler needs to be scaled out, each instance of the endpoint will have different state associated with it.

In general, endpoints should be designed so that [they are idempotent](https://particular.net/blog/what-does-idempotent-mean).

Comment: Thanks for this. Was hoping to find info about handler lifespan/lifestyle in either their assembly scanning, dependency injection, or handler documentation, but couldn't find it.